# Java EE servlet ClassDefNotFound

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new to Java EE.

I wrote a servlet that send back a json as response.
I added Simple Json jar to my project, but when the servlet's doPost() called, I get this error:

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [TodoServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause 
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject

even I added the jar to the class path.
Please help, how can I solve it.

Comment: The jar must be bundled with your webapp, index WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Thanks, now it works.